# How to host a repository in my own site like a PPA?

Tags: repository

As launchpad does not support binary uploads, I want to make .deb packages and host them in My own Github website.

1. How to do it?
2. When done, how to install packages from it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Ubuntu/Debian repository at the minimum consists of a web server directory containing some `.deb` packages and an index file which `apt-get` reads to know which packages and versions are available.

You can read Debian's documentation on how a repository is structured [here](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat). You can also try just navigating a simple PPA repository with your web browser to see how it looks in practice. (Example link: [pypy ppa](http://ppa.launchpad.net/pypy/ppa/ubuntu/)).

If you're planning on updating it only rarely, it is possible to set up the necessary directories and index files by hand, but probably not recommended. A tool like `debarchiver` should help you (although I have not used it personally).

You then just add a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` corresponding to your new repository. Eg, a new file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/myrepo.list` containing:

```
deb http://mysite.com/myrepo precise main
```

Comment: But pypy ppa only has dists and pool folders in root, not the .debs.

Comment: The location of each deb file is given in the `Packages` index. I think you can probably organise the deb files however you want providing the paths are correct. The `dists` dir however needs to have the correct structure to work.