# Where do you guys get the PPA's for installing new software

Tags: software-installation, ppa

Whenever I want to download and install new software on my computer I have to go onto google and type "how to install etc etc" I'm just curious how you guys know the PPA's. Where do you get them?

Comment: generally you should install programs from the software centre where possible, but ppas provide an addional mechansim for getting updates or installing new software. this may be of interest: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them

Comment: I usually do, but sometimes, certain programs on the software centre aren't up to date or the version doesn't work well with my intentions.Also, I just enjoy using the command line sometimes. The question its-self wasn't about what or how, but more of a matter of where, but I thank you for linking me to the other thread as well.

Comment: I find my PPA's on these 2 sites: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/ and http://www.webupd8.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **PPA**, or Personal Package Archive, is a collection of software not included in Ubuntu by default .

So When companies released an updates for their software , you can download them without waiting Ubuntu’s six-month release cycle .

**PPAs** were limited to programmers and testers, but Canonical opened PPAs to everyone in late 2007.

So when companies released updates you can find PPA on its website .

Answer (score 0):

A PPA can be hosted anywhere- on any website. So you won't find a collection of all ppa's together in one place unlike the package repositories hosted on Ubuntu's servers worldwide, unless someone maintains such a repository(will be quite difficult to implement and update).

You could even host your ppa on your own website. See this question to know more on this:

- [How to host a PPA on my own website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367147/how-to-host-a-repository-like-ppa-in-my-own-site)

So, yes unfortunately you will have to google(or search, in other words) to find ppa's for a particular package.